# add_image_size sizes not stored

Tags: images

I am currently working on a function that will do the following:

- Checks if the parameter holds an already created image size and if this size does not exists, create a new one
- Loop through all the image sizes to add these as a source element in the code

This is currently what I have, but the only thing that's bugging me is that when I want to display an image with the newly created size it doesn't recognize the size. I get the following notice: Notice undefined index test.

```
private function checkImageSizes() {

    $exists = false;

    foreach ($this->getSizes() as $size) {

        $exists = false;

        foreach ($this->get_image_sizes() as $currentSizes) {
            if($size['width'] == $currentSizes['width'] && $size['height'] == $currentSizes['height']) {
                $exists = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                $exists = false;
            }
        }

        if($exists == false) {
            if(function_exists('add_image_size')) {
            add_image_size($size['name'], $size['width'], $size['height'], true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I know this question is not new and there are answered, but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hmm... Your code doesn't look right. You loop through all sizes, but if you find first one that already exists, your function returns false - so it wont process any other sizes...

Comment: Is this a method from a class ? why is there private??  Did you hook the it to correct hook??

Comment: This is indeed a method from a Class. I am working like this because I worked with php all the time at school. WordPress is new to me so I am learning some stuff and trying to do it the right way. If you want I can show the rest of the class

Comment: You know that when you run `add_image_size()` it doesn't apply retroactively, right? It will only apply for newly uploaded images. For exisiting images you need to regenerate them. There are several plugins available for this.

Comment: Okay. I looked up a plugin and used it, but I didn't see one of the newly  created custom sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the onyl way of having the permanent image_size is to add them into the functions.php. After adding these sizes I made use of a plugin to regenarte the size of the images.